# Regular expression for a string that contains a sequence that does not begin with a specific character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I've been trying to come up with a regular expression search string that does the following, with no luck:

string contains `ipth` but does not contain `bipth`.  `xipth` is acceptable.  The string can contain anything before or after "ipth".

Any clues?

Comment: Is just `ipth` acceptable?  How about `xxxipth`?

Comment: Please precise the flavor and language : negative look around isn't available in all languages.

Comment: Is `"bipth ipth"` acceptable ?

Comment: @unxnut "xxxipth" is acceptable.

Comment: @dystroy not sure what you mean by flavor, but this will be used in Java 1.5 code.

Comment: Then, the answer will be `[^b]\{1,\}ipth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression

```
([^b]|^)ipth
```

Comment: I see that my answer worked only in some cases and has a mistake as pointed out by Anthony. Yours, OTOH, works in all cases. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!b)ipth
```

The regex `(?<!b)` means "the preceding character must *not* be `b`".

The look-behind also matches start of input, so this expression also matches `ipth` at start of input.